# Creating Slice from Reflected Type

Tags: go, reflection, struct, slice, go-reflect

I am trying to create a slice from a `reflect.Type`. This is what I have so far.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type TestStruct struct {
    TestStr string
}

func main() {
    elemType := reflect.TypeOf(TestStruct{})

    elemSlice := reflect.New(reflect.SliceOf(elemType)).Interface()

    elemSlice = append(elemSlice, TestStruct{"Testing"})

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", elemSlice)

}
```

However I get the following error and I'm not sure how to get around it without hardcoding a conversion to `[]TestStruct`.

```
prog.go:17: first argument to append must be slice; have interface {}
```

Is there anyway to treat the returned interface as a slice without having to hardcode the conversion from `interface{}` to `[]TestStruct`?

Comment: This is acutally more along the lines of what I was looking for. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25384640/why-golang-reflect-makeslice-returns-un-addressable-value

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No, what you describe is not possible. Not type asserting the result of `.Interface()` limits what you can do. Your best chance is to continue to work with the `reflect.Value` value:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type TestStruct struct {
    TestStr string
}

func main() {
    elemType := reflect.TypeOf(TestStruct{})

    elemSlice := reflect.MakeSlice(reflect.SliceOf(elemType), 0, 10)

    elemSlice = reflect.Append(elemSlice, reflect.ValueOf(TestStruct{"Testing"}))

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", elemSlice)

}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/WkGPjv0m_P

Comment: However, elemSlice is still of the type reflect.Value 

How to get this to the actual slice type it is ?

Comment: `elemSlice.Interface().([]TestStruct)`

Answer (score 6):

1- Using `reflect.MakeSlice(reflect.SliceOf(elemType), 0, 10)` and
`reflect.Append(elemSlice, reflect.ValueOf(TestStruct{"Testing"}))`,
Like this working sample code:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"
import "reflect"

func main() {
    elemType := reflect.TypeOf(TestStruct{})
    elemSlice := reflect.MakeSlice(reflect.SliceOf(elemType), 0, 10)
    elemSlice = reflect.Append(elemSlice, reflect.ValueOf(TestStruct{"Testing"}))
    fmt.Println(elemSlice) // [{Testing}]

}

type TestStruct struct {
    TestStr string
}
```

---

2- Using `reflect.New(reflect.SliceOf(elemType)).Elem()` and
`elemSlice = reflect.Append(elemSlice, reflect.ValueOf(TestStruct{"Testing"}))`
Like this working sample code:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"
import "reflect"

type TestStruct struct {
    TestStr string
}

func main() {
    elemType := reflect.TypeOf(TestStruct{})
    elemSlice := reflect.New(reflect.SliceOf(elemType)).Elem()
    elemSlice = reflect.Append(elemSlice, reflect.ValueOf(TestStruct{"Testing"}))

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", elemSlice) // [{TestStr:Testing}]
    fmt.Println(elemSlice)         // [{Testing}]
}
```

Output:

```
[{TestStr:Testing}]
[{Testing}]
```

---

3- If you need `append`, the only way is using `s := elemSlice.([]TestStruct)`, like this working sample code:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"
import "reflect"

type TestStruct struct {
    TestStr string
}

func main() {
    elemType := reflect.TypeOf(TestStruct{})
    elemSlice := reflect.New(reflect.SliceOf(elemType)).Elem().Interface()

    s := elemSlice.([]TestStruct)
    s = append(s, TestStruct{"Testing"})

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", elemSlice) // []
    fmt.Println(s)                 // [{Testing}]
}
```

Comment: So for #3, you still need to write out the actual word "TestStruct".