# JSON marshal of slice made from reflect.New() gives null in golang

Tags: json, go, reflect

I'm using reflect in golang to make a new initialized slice.   But the moment I json.Marshal this new reflected slice, I get a JSON `null` value instead of a `[]`.  See this example here where I compare two cases:

```
package main

import (
  "encoding/json"
  "reflect"
  "log"
)
func makeslice(slice interface{}) interface{} {

  return reflect.New(reflect.TypeOf(slice)).Elem().Interface()
}
func main() {

  s0 := []int{2,3,5}

  s1 := makeslice(s0).([]int)
  js1,e1 := json.Marshal(s1)
  log.Println("case 1:",reflect.TypeOf(s1),reflect.ValueOf(s1),e1,string(js1))

  s2 := []int{}
  js2,e2 := json.Marshal(s2)
  log.Println("case 2:",reflect.TypeOf(s2),reflect.ValueOf(s2),e2,string(js2))

}
```

This gives output of:

```
case 1: []int [] <nil> null
case 2: []int [] <nil> []
```

Notice that `case 1` and `case 2` produce exactly the same log output except for the final json string, where the first case shows `null` and the second case shows `[]`.

Why is this the case?  What I want is for `case 1` to show `[]` instead because my friend's client side application is always expecting an array, and a zero length array should not be shown as a null.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What `reflect.New()` does as per [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#New):

> New returns a Value representing a pointer to a new zero value for the specified type. That is, the returned Value's Type is PtrTo(typ).

In your code, both `s0` and `s2` are not nil. But `s1` will be pointer of **zero value of the `[]int` type, which is `nil`**; since the variable created using `reflect.New()`.

Code below is a proof that slice zero value is `nil`.

```
var a []int = []int{}
log.Printf("%#v \n", a) // ====> []int{}

var b []int
log.Printf("%#v \n", b) // ====> []int(nil)
```

I suggest to use `reflect.MakeSlice()` instead for making a slice. The generated value won't be a `nil`.

```
func makeslice(slice interface{}) interface{} {
    return reflect.MakeSlice(reflect.TypeOf(slice), 0, 0).Interface()
}
```

Then based on your code the output would be:

```
case 1: []int [] <nil> []
case 2: []int [] <nil> []
```

Working playground: https://play.golang.org/p/tL3kFqVwOtC

---

Converting `[]int` with `nil` value into JSON will result `null`. But converting `[]int{}` data into JSON will result `[]` because the data is empty slice (not a nil slice).

---

As followup to comment, this method produces an addressable slice that can be modified further with reflect:

```
func makeslice(slice interface{}) interface{} {
    newsliceval := reflect.MakeSlice(reflect.TypeOf(slice),0,0)
    newslice := reflect.New(newsliceval.Type()).Elem()
    newslice.Set(newsliceval)

    /*
     * make any desired changes to newslice with reflect package
     */

    return newslice.Interface()
}
```

More explanation here
[Why golang reflect.MakeSlice returns un-addressable Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25384640/why-golang-reflect-makeslice-returns-un-addressable-value).

Comment: I needed to combine your solution with what's mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25384640/why-golang-reflect-makeslice-returns-un-addressable-value . The reason I avoided MakeSlice was because it returned an unaddressable value, and hence I couldn't update it.   I ended up using both reflect.MakeSlice and reflect.New together to get a value that can be modified by reflect.